# Как проверить формат даты

Tags: php, yii2

Как проверить формат даты с помощью оператора if.Например:

```
if(/*Если формат даты - 'd/m/Y'*/)
{
  $this->birth_date = Parse::date($this->birth_date, 'd/m/Y', 'Y-m-d'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проверить валидность даты при помощи функции:

```
function validDate($date) { // проверка на правильность формата даты
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('d/m/Y') === $date;
}
```

И проверять валидность даты в теле условного оператора:

```
if(validDate('25/05/2017')) { //true
    //do smth
}
```